# Why we need Activity B to support multiple screens as per android design

Tags: android, android-fragments

As per Android design guidelines to support multiple screens(Phone and tablet),

- In Tablet, we use single activity and load two fragments
- In Phone, we use two activities A and B with master-detail fragments load in each activity.

In phone,why we need to start another activity B and put detail fragment on it? simply we can replace master-fragment by detail-fragment in Activity A itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is certainly possible. It will make Activity A more complicated, though, and overall it may not simplify your app.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, Google now [recommends](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/use-android-jetpack-to-accelerate-your.html?m=1) using a single Activity.

> Today we are introducing the Navigation component as a framework for
>   structuring your in-app UI, with a focus on making a single-Activity
>   app the preferred architecture.